# issue with rails joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models ( just an illustration )

```
Movie   
has_many :usermovies

Usermovie
  belongs_to :user   
  belongs_to :movie

User
  has_many :usermovies
```

Now in a `compare` action

```
@compare_with = User.find(params[:compare_with])
I have  user_ids = [current_user.id,@compare_with.id]
@movies = Movie.joins("usermovies").where('usermovies.user_id' => user_ids)
```

Error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'movies': SELECT `movies`.* FROM `movies` usermovies WHERE `usermovies`.`user_id` IN (3, 1)

Extracted source (around line #9):

6:   <td><%= "#{@compare_with.name}'s rating" %> </td>
7: </thead>
8: <tbody>
9:   <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
10:   <td></td>
11:   <td></td>
12:   <% end %>
```

But when I use `:includes` instead of `:joins` it just works great.

any ideas what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `.joins("usermovies")`.

You must either pass symbols, eg:

```
joins(:usermovies)
```

Or else, if you pass a string:

```
joins("JOIN usermovies")
```

This is because when you pass a string, Rails expects you to also specify the `JOIN` type. This functionality is particularly useful if you want to change the default `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. However, since Rails does not know if you want to change the join type, if you pass a string, you must explicitly include `JOIN` in the string even if you do not want to change the join type.

Comment: 1 query does'nt `includes` have such constraint ?

Comment: `includes` is implemented as a separate query. There is no join required.